# How to remove single quote in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The following query works if I save it as query in Access

```
UPDATE Tbl_Invoices SET Tbl_Invoices.[Name] = Replace([Name],"'","")
WHERE (((Tbl_Invoices.Update_date)=Date()));
```

but when I try to convert it into VBA as below I have a syntax error

```
UPDATE Tbl_Invoices SET Tbl_Invoices.[Name] = Replace([Name],''','') WHERE (((Tbl_Invoices.Update_date)=Date()));
```

I know I am missing something obvious but I cannot see it.

Comment: You are not showing complete VBA. What data type is Currency? Why does it have apostrophe? `Replace([Currency], ""'"", """")` or `Replace([Currency], ""'"", '')` or `Replace([Currency], Chr(39), '')`

Comment: Why not have VBA call the stored query: `CurrentDb.Execute myUpdateQuery`? Access stored queries are usually more efficient to run and you avoid mixing/concatenating languages.

Comment: Something is very wrong here; _Currency_, neither amounts nor codes, contains single quotes.

Comment: @June7 I am re-using the field for different purposes. I have renamed it in the question now to avoid misunderstandings. I just want to delete the apostrophe in the field

Comment: @Gustav I am re-using the field for different purposes. I have renamed it in the question now to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: @Parfait If I store the query then it works perfectly. I just wanted to have it in the code as it looked neater. I still don't know when it is better to use a stored query or one coded in the source.

Comment: SQL in VBA being neater? I find it messier and harder to read given VBA's line breaks and concatenation operators and quote handling as you encountered. Often a well discussed topic, in Access, usually stored queries are more efficient since the engine saves best execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Sql As String

Sql = _
    "UPDATE Tbl_Invoices " & _
    "SET [Name] = Replace([Name], ""'"", """") " & _
    "WHERE Update_date = Date();"
```